# Using Holt's Method, but my data has zeros. What options do I have?

Tags: python, statsmodels, holtwinters

I am using the following code to execute Holt's method with statsmodels, but my data may legitimately have a zero value at times. This leads to the error message "NotImplementedError: Unable to correct for negative or zero values."

Does anybody know what my options are to correct this? I noticed if I take out exponential = True, it'll work, but my forecast is terrible. So, I'd really like to include it.

```
fit2 = Holt(ts, exponential=True).fit(smoothing_level=0.8, smoothing_slope=0.2, optimized=False)
fcast2 = fit2.forecast(8).rename("Exponential trend")
```

My data is weekly and looks like this:

```
START_TIME
2016-07-09      1.125
2016-07-16      0.000
2016-07-23     18.096
2016-07-30     47.769
2016-08-06     47.540
2016-08-13     31.298
2016-08-20     27.628
2016-08-27     35.846
2016-09-03     21.439
2016-09-10     61.749
```

Comment: do you want to skip the 0 values and smooth the rest? or do you want the 0 values to become smoothed non zero values?

Comment: I'm not sure which is best. I was thinking of setting the zero values to something that's very small. How would you approach the two options you described?

Comment: Probably somebody else has to answer there, but it depends on the data, what it represents and why you want to use the Holt method. 

As you don't specify where from you import the holt method we don't even know what exactly the Holt method is. Do you mean Holt's Linear Trend Method (aka Double Exponential Smoothing). If yes, then you talk about a function, that should indicate a trending function.

Comment: Are the 0 values real measured 0 values, that should be smoothed out or a place holder for measures not being taken / to be considered.

Did you read the documentation of the library, the implements the Holt function.
Perhaps it mentions what to do in such cases.

technically your approach to just replace 0 with a small value (e.g. 0.1) will work out, but whether this gives the desired results or whether it would be better to just skip the 0 values is something I cant say. Perhaps somebody with better stats knowledge can contribute.

Comment: The 0 values are real measured 0 values.